# Firebase Cloud Messaging on iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to use Firebase Cloud Messaging on my iPhone 6 running iOS 11.4, when the web app tries to initialize FCM, the following message shows up

`FirebaseError: Messaging: This browser doesn't support the API's required to use the firebase SDK`

Device: iPhone 6
iOS version: 11.4
FCM JS SDK version: 5.0.4
Safari version: 11.0 (As seen form `navigator.appVersion`)
Chrome version: 67.0.3396.87

Comment: Are you using any content blockers?

Comment: @EnricoSusatyo no, I reset the iPhone before the testing

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50433873/reactjs-fcm-not-working-in-safari-browser)

Comment: @Kerberos thanks for your input, however FCM isn't working on Chrome 67 on the same device too. (Question updated)

Comment: What version of Firebase, XCode and Swift is it? Have you updated your pod recently?

Comment: @Jay my app is a web app, so Xcode isn't involved. The error message comes from the JavaScript console.

Comment: You should include the relevant tags in your question (Javascript for example) and can you include what versions you are using?

Comment: @Jay That's why I am using the `pwa` tag