# Firebase Messaging on IOS web browsers

Tags: firebase, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

Firebase messaging push notifications work Desktop and Android web browsers without any problem but when I tested it on IOS devices it doesn't matter which browser I used, notifications and .getToken() method not working. My JavaScript code is that:

```
if ('Notification' in window) {
    var messaging = firebase.messaging();
    if (Notification.permission === 'granted') {
        subscribe();
    }

    $('#notify').on('click', function () {
        subscribe();
    });
}

function subscribe() {
    // запрашиваем разрешение на получение уведомлений
    messaging.requestPermission()
        .then(function () {
            // получаем ID устройства
            return messaging.getToken()
                .then(function (currentToken) {
                    console.log(currentToken);

                    if (currentToken) {
                        sendTokenToServer(currentToken);
                    } else {
                        console.warn('Не удалось получить токен.');
                        setTokenSentToServer(false);
                    }
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    console.warn('При получении токена произошла ошибка.', err);
                    setTokenSentToServer(false);
                });
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.warn('Не удалось получить разрешение на показ уведомлений.', err);
        });
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All browsers on iOS are essentially wrappers around WebKit (the browser engine that is used in Safari), so they inherit most of their features and limitations from there. Unfortunately Safari still doesn't support the Web Push API, that is required for Firebase Cloud Messaging.

Also see:

- [Push notifications in Apple Safari with FCM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45555067/push-notifications-in-apple-safari-with-fcm)
- [ReactJS - FCM not working in safari browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50433873/reactjs-fcm-not-working-in-safari-browser)
- the [Firebase Cloud Messaging for web documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client)
- the [caniuse.com page for the push API](https://caniuse.com/#feat=push-api)

Answer (score 1):

Web push notification works on Home Screen web apps in iOS 16.4 or later.

Also see:
[Sending web push notifications in web apps, Safari, and other browsers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/sending_web_push_notifications_in_web_apps_safari_and_other_browsers)